# php and XML range into array

Tags: php, xml, range

The code below helps be to get the WHOLE XML and put it into an array. What I'm wondering is, what would be a good way to get the XML only from item 3 - 6 or any arbitrary range instead of the whole document.

```
 $d = new DOMDocument();
 $d->load('http://news.google.com/?output=rss');
 foreach ($d->getElementsByTagName('item') as $t) {
  $list = array ( 'title' => $t->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue);
  array_push($mt_arr, $list);
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Xpath.

You can either use DOMXpath or use the xpath method to create an Xpath query that will return the subset of nodes.

```
$d->xpath('/SOME/XPATH/STATEMENT');
```